# How to create OpenGL ES 2 context on Desktop?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es-2.0, x11

Is it possible to create **OpenGL ES 2** context on desktop linux?

My context related code is like this:

```
int context_attribs[] =
      {
        GLX_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 4,
        GLX_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 5,
        GLX_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB, GLX_CONTEXT_ES2_PROFILE_BIT_EXT,
        None
      };

    ctx = glXCreateContextAttribsARB( display, bestFbc, 0,
                                      True, context_attribs );
```

But it fails.

However this succeeds:

```
int context_attribs[] =
          {
            GLX_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 4,
            GLX_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 5,
            GLX_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB, GLX_CONTEXT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE_BIT_ARB,
            None
          };
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I am trying to do this on Fedora 22 x86_64 with NVIDIA GTX 750 Ti GPU.

**UPDATE**

Here's the working code to create OpenGL ES 2.0 context based on answer below:

https://github.com/manmohanbishnoi/my-experiments/blob/master/OpenGL%20ES%20context%20on%20Desktop/opengl_es2.c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are requesting an OpenGL ES version 4.5 context, which does not exist. From the [`GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile` extension spec:](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/glx_create_context_es2_profile.txt)

> If the version requested is a valid and supported OpenGL-ES version,
>       and the `GLX_CONTEXT_ES_PROFILE_BIT_EXT` bit is set in the
>       `GLX_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB` attribute (see below), then the context
>       returned will implement the OpenGL ES version requested.

The `GLX_CONTEXT_ES2_PROFILE_BIT_EXT` is actually kind of a red herring:

> Version 3, 2012/03/28
>
> - Add support for any OpenGL-ES version, not
>     just version 2.0. **Alias `GLX_CONTEXT_ES2_PROFILE_BIT_EXT` with
>     `GLX_CONTEXT_ES_PROFILE_BIT_EXT`** and the extension name
>     `GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile` with
>     `GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile`.

So it doesn't select a version at all in a profile, version and profile are working orthogonally...

Comment: changing MAJOR and MINOR version to 2 an 0 respectively worked !